# How to improve cooling of my ASUS ROG?

Tags: cooling, computer-building, temperature

I have a notebook ASUS ROG g551jm-cn102h and it has high temperatures, from 50° to 55° when I switch on it but when I open Google Chrome or YouTube, the temperature reaches about 70° or over 80°. What should I do?

Comment: Open it up, clean dust out of fans, make sure that thermal pads are making solid contact. Replace thermal materials if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use Compressed Air Cans to remove dust from the cooling fans.You can also try undervolting your CPU with Intel XTU(helps with temps on my GL503).

I would not recommend repasting the thermal compound if your laptop is under warranty otherwise you can refer to [this article](https://www.timesdigit.com/best-thermal-paste.html) for the best thermal compounds.

REPASTE WITH UTMOST CAUTION AS SPILLAGE CAN DAMAGE COMPONENTS (I suggest you do some research about repasting laptops first)

Hope this helps. Cheers!